# Bounce invalid dynamic email address from PHP through postfix pipe

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

I have a web application in PHP that allows users to create documents and send them as PDF attached to an email.
Originally, it was sent with a reply-to pointing to the user's email address, but I am implementing an internal email address system. The goal is to keep all the replies to the original email related to a specific document in the application.

All internal addresses start with *PREFIX* followed by delimiter "-". Postfix processes all email sent to *PREFIX*@mydomain.com through a pipe to a PHP script that tries to match the address to a specific user and document (eg: *PREFIX*-*U1A*-*DJX8*@mydomain.com refers to document JX8 of user 1A)

Everything works well but I am wondering how to handle invalid emails:

When no document is found related to the address, it is most probably spam.

However it's possible someone manually wrote the address and was mistaken, in that case the sender should be notified.

Should I simply send a generic mail from the PHP script to the sender stating the address is invalid?

Or is there a way to send a bounce either through the script or to tell postfix to handle it?